# If $\mu_n(A) \to \mu(A)$ for every $A$ such that $\mu(\partial A) = 0$, why does $\mu_n([0,x]) \to \mu([0,x])$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X = [0,1]$, and suppose $\mu_n$ is a sequence of finite measures on $(X, \mathcal{B}(X))$. Let $\mu$ be another finite measure on this space, and suppose that for each Borel set $A \subset [0,1]$ such that $\mu(\partial A) = 0$ we have $\mu_n(A) \to \mu(A)$ as $n \to \infty$.

I am trying to show that $\mu_n([0,x]) \to \mu([0,x])$ for each $x$ such that $\mu(\{x\}) = 0$. If $\mu(\{0\}) = 0$ this is immediate. I also know that there can be at most countably many singleton sets $\{x\}$ of positive measure. How can I show that $\mu_n(\{0\}) \to \mu(\{0\})$?

Could someone please give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem true. Let $\mu_n = \delta_{\frac{1}{n}}$ (ie $\mu_n(\{\frac{1}{n}\}) = 1$ and $\mu_n\left([0, 1] \setminus \{\frac{1}{n}\}\right) = 0$ and $\mu_n = \delta_0$.

If $0 \notin \delta A$, then either $[0, x] \subset A$ for some $x > 0$ or $[0, x] \cap A = \varnothing$ for some $x > 0$. In the former case, $\mu(A) = 1$ and $\mu_n(A) = 1$ for $n > \frac{1}{x}$. In the later case, $\mu(A) = 0$ and $\mu_n(A) = 0$ for $n > \frac{1}{x}$. In both cases, $\mu_n(A) \to \mu(A)$.

However, $\mu(\{0\}) = 1$ and $\mu_n(\{0\}) = 0 \not \to 1$.